# Racket enforce input types for function

Tags: racket, typed-racket

I'd like to enforce the data type for input to a function in racket. For example, in this function I want to expect integers and throw an error if someone inputs a string.

Is there a standard way to enforce this in Racket?

```
(sum-coins pennies nickels dimes quarters)
  pennies : integer?
  nickels : integer?
  dimes : integer?
  quarters : integer?
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there are two standard ways.

## Contracts

[Contracts](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/contracts.html) check conditions and raise errors at runtime:

```
#lang racket

(define/contract (sum-coins pennies nickels dimes quarters)
  (-> integer? integer? integer? integer? integer?)
  (+ (* 1 pennies)
     (* 5 nickels)
     (* 10 dimes)
     (* 25 quarters)))

(sum-coins 1 2 3 4)
;; => 141
(sum-coins "1" 2 3 4)
; sum-coins: contract violation
;   expected: integer?
;   given: "1"
;   in: the 1st argument of
;       (->
;        integer?
;        integer?
;        integer?
;        integer?
;        integer?)
;   contract from: (function sum-coins)
;   blaming: /tmp/so.rkt
;    (assuming the contract is correct)
;   at: /tmp/so.rkt:3.18
; Context (errortrace):
;    /tmp/so.rkt:11:0: (sum-coins "1" 2 3 4)
;    /tmp/so.rkt:11:0: (sum-coins "1" 2 3 4)
```

## Typed Racket

Or you can use [Typed Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/index.html), which checks types at compile time:

```
#lang typed/racket

(define (sum-coins [pennies : Integer]
                   [nickels : Integer]
                   [dimes : Integer]
                   [quarters : Integer])
  (+ (* 1 pennies)
     (* 5 nickels)
     (* 10 dimes)
     (* 25 quarters)))

(sum-coins 1 2 3 4)
;; => 141
(sum-coins "1" 2 3 4)
; /tmp/so2.rkt:14:11: Type Checker: type mismatch
;   expected: Integer
;   given: String
;   in: "1"
```